MigLayout How To Make Only Last Column Grow
Here is my code:
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().debug().fillX(), new AC().align("left").gap("rel").grow().fill(), new AC().gap("10")));
JPanel groupBySourcePanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().debug().fillX(), new AC().align("left").grow().fill(), new AC().gap("10")));
groupBySourcePanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
JPanel groupByTypePanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().debug().fillX(), new AC().align("left").grow().fill(), new AC().gap("10")));
groupByTypePanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));

mainPanel.add(new JLabel("REALTIME STATS"), "span 3, wrap, center");
mainPanel.add(new JLabel("All data count"));
mainPanel.add(new JLabel(":"));
mainPanel.add(new JLabel("5043"), "wrap");
groupByTypePanel.add(new JLabel("Group by Type"), "span 3, wrap");
groupByTypePanel.add(new JLabel("Type A"));
groupByTypePanel.add(new JLabel(":"));
groupByTypePanel.add(new JLabel("5043"), "wrap");
groupByTypePanel.add(new JLabel("Type B"));
groupByTypePanel.add(new JLabel(":"));
groupByTypePanel.add(new JLabel("5043"), "wrap");
mainPanel.add(groupByTypePanel, "growx, span 3, wrap");
groupBySourcePanel.add(new JLabel("Group by Source"), "span 3, wrap");
groupBySourcePanel.add(new JLabel("Source A"));
groupBySourcePanel.add(new JLabel(":"));
groupBySourcePanel.add(new JLabel("5043"), "wrap");
groupBySourcePanel.add(new JLabel("Source B"));
groupBySourcePanel.add(new JLabel(":"));
groupBySourcePanel.add(new JLabel("5043"), "wrap");
mainPanel.add(groupBySourcePanel, "growx, span 3, wrap");

And here is the result:

In that image, mainPanel row only grow 2nd and 3rd column, 1st column didn't.
But the groupBy...Panel grow all its column.
Actually, what I want is to make the ":" character in every row aligned nicely. How it can be done?
